# Is there a way for some grid items to start from left and some for the right in same line?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, grid

I created a navbar using grid layout.

[image: Grid Photo]

**HTML**

```
<nav className="nav nav_dark">
    <h1 className="logo white">Menu</h1>
    <div className="menu white">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Support</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>About Me</a></li>
            <li className='buttonlist'><button>Reach me</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px;
    grid-column-gap: 300px;
}

.nav_dark {
    background-color: #1d1733;
}

.menu {
    margin: auto;
}

.menu > ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu > ul > .buttonlist {
    margin: 0 50px;
}

.menu > ul > li > button {
    padding: 15px 60px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: #c746eb;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.logo {
    margin: auto;
}
```

The thing I want to achieve here is to have the `logo` which is currently just a `h1` with Menu value to start from left like `float: left;` and the buttons to start from right like `float: right;`.

I tried the `float` but couldn't achieve what I wanted since you can't use `float` with `grid`, I guess(?).

Can someone tell me if there is a way to do it or at least show me the right way?

**PS:** I am currently using `React`.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob I'll try it now but I don't think It'll work since the 50% of a div is 50% of its designated area which is 1`fr` and 3`fr` respectively, but I'm not so sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text-align` like below code:

```css
.nav {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px;
   // grid-column-gap: 300px;


}

.nav_dark {
    background-color: #1d1733;
}

.menu {
  //  margin: auto;
      text-align:right;

}

.menu > ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.menu > ul > .buttonlist {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.menu > ul > li > button {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: #c746eb;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.logo {
    margin: auto 10px;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;

}
```

```html
<nav class="nav nav_dark">
       <h1 class="logo white">Menu</h1>
    <div class="menu white">
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Support</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>About Me</a></li>
            <li class='buttonlist'><button>Reach me</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</nav>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted, thank you. And I want to ask something, Is there any way to refer a parent element in CSS? I mean I gave a class to `<li class='buttonlist'><button>Reach me</button></li>`just to reach the `li`with a button in it. Is there any way of me to refer that lee without specifying a class for it?

Comment: yeah, use `li:last-child{ }` instead buttonlist class.

Comment: But doesn't it points the button inside the li? @kian 

**Edit** Alright It works, thanks :)